# Managed property not showing office 365

Tags: office-365, managed-property

I have a managed property in office 365 which doesn't show in one site collection but does in all the others.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> You have to perform a full crawl of the content source or sources that
>   contain this new managed property to include it in the search index.
>   If the new managed property is in a SharePoint library or list, you
>   have to reindex that library or list.
>   https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219667.aspx#proc7

As you are in the Office 365, i would do following.

Make sure my site collection crawled after the Managed Property created.The full reindex of the list or library will be performed during the next scheduled crawl.

You can also Contact the Office 365 Support and check if they can behind the scene.